# Is it correct to say "The bolt has an external male thread" and "The nut has an internal female thread"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

I think each bolt has just one thread and each nut has just one thread, too.

If a bolt had 2 threads, it would mess things up.

Is it correct to say "**The bolt has an external male thread**" and "**The nut has an internal female thread**" and "**This nut doesn't fit tight on this bolt. I think the thread of either the bolt or the nut are worn**"?

Comment: "Internal" and "external" are redundant. This is implied by "female" and "male" respectively. "The threads are worn" and the nut doesn't fit tightly anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it correct to say "The bolt has an external male thread" and "The nut has an internal female thread"

It is technically correct but redundant. A bolt is a threaded male fastener, and the thread will always be on the contact surface, which is the outside for a male fastener. Similar for a nut.

> "This nut doesn't fit tight on this bolt. I think the thread of either the bolt or the nut are worn"?

“thread” is singular, which requires “is” rather than “are”, but otherwise correct.

You could also say “threads ... are”, which is common even when there’s technically only one thread.